# Too many recent calls error from YouTube API

Tags: youtube

There is an issue with you tube API quota where within a couple of requests i am receiving the error >yt:quota`too_many_recent_calls` . I did read other posts made on this issue but didn`t find a solution.
The site has a cron job set up to once a week. I have inserted the developer key and the site is only in testing mode and i believe the site has not made excesive calls to you tube videos.
Not sure what to do as the video section of the site is basically useless. Would appreciate if someone would help.
Thanks